# Preserving whitespace with .split()?

Tags: ruby

I have to reverse words in a string. All whitespaces need to be preserved.

```
def reverse_words(str)
  array = str.split

    new_sentence = []
    array.each do |word|
        word.reverse!
        new_sentence << word
    end
    new_sentence.join(" ")
end
```

I'm getting the output "elbuod decaps sdrow" when I am wanting "elbuod  decaps  sdrow" with the double spaces preserved.

What's the best way to go about doing this? I can't quite figure it out on my own. Everything I've come across is about removing whitespace not preserving it.

Comment: @anothermh the editor automatically removes double spaces for some reason. and what does reverse have to do with preserving spaces in a sentence? .reverse also reverses the order. Thats why I made an array to preserve the word order and only reverse spelling not the entire sentence.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. You didn’t include your input.

Comment: @anothermh i figured out the solution. Posted it below. Still don't know why it worked though lol.

Comment: Alternatively `str.gsub(/\S+/, &:reverse)` – avoids the intermediate array and doesn't have whitespace issues.

Comment: @Stefan thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Ruby doc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-split) for pattern-based splitting says:

> If pattern is a String, then its contents are used as the delimiter
>   when splitting str. If pattern is a single space, str is split on
>   whitespace, with leading and trailing whitespace and runs of
>   contiguous whitespace characters ignored.

In other words, `split(" ")` will treat any number of spaces as a unit to be split around:

```
"hello   world".split(" ")  # => ["hello", "world"]
```

Alternatively:

> If pattern is a Regexp, str is divided where the pattern matches.
>   Whenever the pattern matches a zero-length string, str is split into
>   individual characters. If pattern contains groups, the respective
>   matches will be returned in the array as well.

Consequently, `split(/ /)` will treat every space as a different point to split, and `split(/(\s+)/)` (as proposed by darclander) will include the multiple space elements in the result.  Illustrating this with underscores instead of spaces:

```
"hello___world".split(/_/)  # =>  ["hello", "", "", "world"]
"hello___world".split(/(_+)/)  # => ["hello", "___", "world"]
```

Given that reversing spaces gives the same number of spaces, a quick solution looks like:

```
"hello   world".split(/(\s+)/).map(&:reverse).join  # => "olleh   dlrow"
```

---

As pointed out by Cary Swoveland, you may want to preserve output spacing in the case of mixed types of whitespace. Consider replacing `map(&:reverse)` with a block that preserves whitespace but reverses non-whitespace, such as `map { |s| s.strip.empty? ? s : s.reverse }`.

Comment: There is a problem when a block of whitespace contains different whitespace characters (a space and a tab, for example), for their positions are reversed. You might replace `map(&:reverse)` with `map { |s| s.strip.empty? ? s : s.reverse }`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the string

```
str = "Now is    the time\n    \tto hunker down"
```

To reverse each word and preserve whitespace one would would want to return

```
"woN si    eht emit\n    \tot reknuh nwod"
```

The easiest way to do that is to use [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub):

```
str.gsub(/\w+/) { |s| s.reverse }
  #=> "woN si    eht emit\n    \tot reknuh nwod"
```

Comment: The only drawback I see is if the original problem was an exercise to emphasize some of the subtleties of `split`, since your solution doesn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
array = str.split(/ /)
```

This change on line 2 fixed it. Not quite sure why though. Can someone explain the difference between .split(/ /) and .split(" ")

Comment: Have you checked the split API? https://apidock.com/ruby/String/split

Comment: I believe `str.split(/(\s+)/)` would work the same.

Comment: @darclander yeah, but i havent found a good place to learn all the crazy regex stuff. have any recommendations?

Comment: I mean there are "tutorials" https://www.rubyguides.com/2015/06/ruby-regex/ or http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/advanced/regular_expressions.html that go through some of the more common ones. I also think you learn about it when you make your own projects!

Comment: No problem! If you think any of the comments helped you can upvote them! Also I do not want to sound rude but I think according to stackoverflow they want us to avoid comments such as "thanks" etc. Hopefully things are working out for you now though!